# Paypal IPN listener INVALID most of the time

Tags: php, paypal

I have this strange problem where some IPN verification return INVALID.

The type of IPN is subscr_payment.
The other types like subscr_eot or subscr_cancel are verified just fine.

I use `ipnlistener.php`

Nothing fancy with it. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There must be something about the way you're sending the data back to PayPal for those types of transactions that it doesn't like.  Are you re-formatting amounts or anything like that?

You need to send it back to PayPal exactly as they send it to you in order for it to validate.

Comment: yes, I found the issue, there was a SSL certificate required in the curl config. Strange only subscr_payment required it.